# struts2 spring form submit error

Tags: forms, spring, error-handling, struts2, submit

I have an online application http://www.eworkshop.co.in  developed using stuts2 and spring framework.  When I submit the login form with correct inputs, it work fines. 
when I test with incorrect data, it shows me errors as expected. But here If I use correct data again (after using wrong data once), It shows me same error msg without submitting form.It is not going to action class even , directly shows me error page like html redirection.

goto http://www.eworkshop.co.in. click on my account. try with correct ,incorrect and than correct data again. here problem occurs.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: This is not related to your problem but i just wanted to appreciate the UI design there. Which library are you using for those charts?

Comment: thanks. I am using google chart API.

Answer (score 0):

In your case if i am understanding your case correctly server side things are not getting triggered at all.that means neither Struts2 or Spring coming to work.

i suspect it is a problem with browser side caching mechanism.can you explain a bit how you doing the loin process and how you handling login error in your application.Are you using Struts2 validation framework or using your own mechanism for this?

Comment: yes you got it correctly. If I am login using correct data after trying with wrong data, nothing at server side gets invoked.

Comment: @jeet: i suspect that it is more of a browser issue. i tried at your website but not sure what are test user-id and password so was not able to check the behaviour

Comment: it is there . try with test/xyz@test.com . for wrong data you can enter anything.

Comment: i tried with them it saying "Either Id or Email is wrong. Please try again."

Comment: can you please re-try. I have bounced servers and its working fine. before login you just clear your cache

Comment: i checked that and it seems a pure client side cache or some other issue.specify how you doing validation and showing error as it can help to debug issue

Comment: I am not able to add code piece here. It scatters without formatting

Comment: add code to your own question it will help other community members to get more details

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. It was because of addActionError("") in action class. error was getting cached. I removed this and used a boolean flag to check whether error exists or not. it worked perfectly.